# JAVA class turned into xml file

Tags: java, android

Everything was fine. I just built it yesterday. Today, while I opened this most of my JAVA classes code, turned into xml. I don't know what kind of strange reason it is.

I tried 2 options below but nothing worked :

1. **File** > **Sync project with Gradle files**. Result: didn't solved my problem.
2. **File** > **Invalidated cache/restart**. Result: didn't solved my problem.

I attached a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Just found [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53070966/5015207) - different yet similar - case of Android Studio misbehaving. Which Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: I suspect this has to do with not closing Android Studio correctly, do you have  the same notion? I hade some laptop crashes this week and [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53070966/5015207) similar Question as yours

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for [me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53070966/5015207). Keep Android Studio open and go into the file system. Open every java source file and all xml files into some editor(Notepad++) and change something then save the file back to origin.

Now Android Studio detect all files as normal

Answer (score 2):

Android studio: Click on malfunction file then Right-click -> Open in -> Explorer.
Choose your file where was the problem and open them with Notepad.
And change something, like adding the space and save it.

And Sometimes Android studio turns files into UTF8-BOM. It needs to change to UTF-8. You may do with NotePad++ -> Encoding.