# Android Java source java files opens as png files something

Tags: android, android-studio

Today Android Studio started to behave strange. Source java files opens
as png files something. I can build and run the app and if I look in the file system the java files looks ok. I do Invalidate cache and restart, I delete .idea and build folders but no change. The strange thing is I can debug run the app. If I want to change java files I have to open like Notepad and save then build project again

There must be some file/setting in Android studio that control this. I delete the project ide and build folded but no change, where in Android Studio can I reset this to start working normal?
[image]

Comment: Looks weird - and not the first case today of Android Studio misbehaving, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53070378/5015207). Which Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: Yes thanks same problem, Halloween? I use Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Have you tried to click at message Hyperlink?

Comment: I suspect this has to do with not closing Android Studio correctly,  I hade some laptop crashes this week

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that worked for me.
I hade to open every java source file and all xml files into a text editor(Notepad++) and change something then save the file back to origin.

Now Android Studio detect all files as normal

Comment: This happened to me too. I've been using Linux for years, but I had to start developing on Win10 for some other reasons. 
Good to know you a found something that works for you. My project, though, is to big to think that's a good idea to replicate...

Comment: UPDATE: Ok, my easy way of solving this, was to delete the entire project and checkout it again from git. 
I think the issue could be cause by some corruption during indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this:

Close Android Studio and delete the caches folder:

`C:\Users\user_name\.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches`

Answer (score 0):

When you save a file at notepad and open it in Android Studio, it will happen because notepad use a different encoding (ANSI).

You can set your project file encodings at `Settings->Editor->File Encodings`

[image]

You can also edit a unique file encoding at `File->File Encoding`

Make sure your project file encoding is UTF-8 (default)

[image]

Another important setting is File Types that you can take a look too. Here is mine .java file setting to you as example.

[image]

Comment: Thanks what you suggest is ok but it did not help me I posted an answer to my own Q