# How to fix if android studio changes codes automatically?

Tags: android

Android Studio is changing my java codes or layout codes automatically and I dont understand why this is happening. That code has come instead of my xml layout code.

```
<component name="libraryTable">
<library name="Gradle: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3@aar">
    <CLASSES>
        <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/aa9595f9274afa3bfa3bad4cb4d514ab/res" />
        <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/aa9595f9274afa3bfa3bad4cb4d514ab/jars/classes.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
</library>
</component>
```

Comment: Some more information would be good, what has changed?

Comment: Go ahead and add your code so we can better help.

Comment: <component name="libraryTable">
<library name="Gradle: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3@aar">

Comment: It create something like that instead of my layout xml file. Also gradle files are damaged with meaningless characters like ����   3V
 QST actionBarDivider I

Comment: Look at [this maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070966/android-java-source-java-files-opens-as-png-files-something)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)